# How to convert layer.shadowOffset(x, y) of a rotated view in order to draw it correctly in a graphics context?

Tags: swift, uigraphicscontext

Problem: I have a `UIImageView` that can be rotated, the shadow moves with the rotation which is fine...

```
UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { [self] in
            artArray[selectedArt].transform = artArray[selectedArt].transform.rotated(by: -.pi / 2)
        }
```

But later when I combine multiple images into one image in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` `draw(in:)` method, the shadow is in the wrong position. I understand that when a view is rotated the bounds is also rotated for example: 0,0 of a rectangular imageView that has been rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise is now going to be in the bottom left corner.

Is there a way I can convert a rotated views `layer.shadowOffset(x, y)` to reflect the rotation?

Currently I can convert it manually for example `layer.shadowOffset(x: 1, y: 1)` on a view that has been rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise needs to be drawn as `context.setShadow(offset: (x: -1, y: 1)` to reflect the same shadow position that is on the device screen.

Is there a way I can do this dynamically?

I can't use `drawViewHierarchyInRect` as during `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` I am swapping out the images on screen for full size images in order to export HD photos.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Solution:**

Solution using calculations @Larme suggested for anyone that needs similar solution.

```
func correctOffset(angle: CGFloat, offset: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let unroundedX = offset.height * CGFloat(sinf(Float(angle))).rounded() + offset.width * CGFloat(cosf(Float(angle))).rounded()
    let unroundedY = offset.height * CGFloat(cosf(Float(angle))) - offset.width * CGFloat(sinf(Float(angle)))
    x = round(unroundedX * 10) / 10
    y = round(unroundedY * 10) / 10
    return CGSize(width: x, height: y)
}
```

Comment: Here you have I guess how is made the calculation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455666-cgaffinetransformmakerotation?language=objc see the "These are the resulting equations used to apply the rotation to a point (x, y):" I guess it might work in your case, you might get the new `offset` with that.

Comment: Wow yes that was what I needed! thanks for that.